# Modal: using modal within elements that were loaded via AJAX after document.load()

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

**What happened:** I have a page where user has to click on a button and selection is displayed in modal. When they clicked on what ever they wanted div element on the page is updated, via AJAX, which shows what they have selected and has an option "view item".

I have defined that "view item" should open up another modal view which will have all the information on the item, and now, referring to the above paragraph, rather then opening modal view user is being transferred to that page?

**Question:**
Is their a walk around for modal to be activated on the elements that were loaded after document load stage?

**Example code:** On initial load user is presented with following code, at this example item was set prior to load:

```
<div id="dynamic-area">
    Item 1
    <a href="selection/view/1" data-tip="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View" data-toggle="modal">view selection</a> 
</div>

<input type="radio" name="selection" id="selection" value="" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="/selection/search/1"  />Change selection
```

When user have picked a different item after clicking on "change selection" #dynamic-area was fully updated with a data that was fetched via AJAX on the selected item.

So lets say, if user have picked item 3, we would have code below:

```
<div id="dynamic-area">
    Item 3
    <a href="selection/view/3" data-tip="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="View" data-toggle="modal">view selection</a> 
</div>

<input type="radio" name="selection" id="selection" value="" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="/selection/search/1"  />Change selection
```

Now if user to click on the "view selection", user is being to the page 'selection/view/3' when user should see modal.

Comment: that should not be happening, maybe your id's are wrong. while data-target="#myModal" of your button and id="myModal" in your modal matches all should work.

Comment: Could you please view an updated description, I have included example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extending this function action worked as it should